# being in the city ‘off-limits’ or ‘inconceivable’ as much as conceivable

Tags: history-of-philosophy, political-philosophy

Can anybody explain what the bold sentence want to say?

> Context:
>
> And whilst cities obviously contain bodies, bodies also contain
>   cities. In fact, the city itself functions as an ‘ecological’ body,
>   one that facilitates the circulation of particular socio-economic and
>   cultural discourses whilst also thereby delimiting them. In other
>   words, the city’s practices install constitutive effects and
>   behaviours in the body of its citizenry that **implicitly render some
>   ways of being in the city ‘off-limits’ or ‘inconceivable’ as much as
>   conceivable**.

Answer (score 2):

"The people can't imagine breaking some of the city's rules."

Comment: can you please explain a little more?

Answer (score 0):

You really should give a reference and context. But the language sounds familiar enough. I would tend to agree that Shane's neat deflation is basically correct.

This is a textbook sort of *post-modernist* rhetoric that might be enlightening by recasting our way of seeing things. But here it just sounds a bit bloated and unoriginal (depending on context), and can be edited down to Shane's 10 words without losing anything except ambience.

It points to the oddity of the fact that in cities, dense with organized subjectivity, there are many more "rules" than are apparent. There are many things we "don't do" that we learn by collective habit without any laws or anyone explicitly saying so.

The writer says these become not actually *impossible* but "inconceivable." Which could be an interesting distinction. Except that the writer, at least in this excerpt, goes on to say "as much as conceivable." Which just sounds like sloppy writing or obscurantism.

Comment: So, does it mean that cities not only provide us with different ways of behavior, but also prevent us from some other behaviors? In other words, imposing limitations as much as freedom?

Any way, I can not find any relation to @shane 's answer. I can not understand the relationship between them.

Comment: That sounds about right. The old phrase "Stadt Luft macht frei" or "city air makes us free," expressed freedom from church, feudal lords, and local authority found in the cities. But under modernity new "rules" of behavior emerge. You don't, for example, just sit down on the sidewalk or grow vegetables in the parking strip. You would not even find it "conceivable." Shane's answer reduces this to the basics, there are "rules" and people can't even "imagine" breaking them. By stating it so curtly he is critiquing the pretentious rhetoric of the author, who isn't really saying anything more.